# How to get a column of data from ADO.NET Datatable USING GROUP BY a column?

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable as Following

```
ID  ITEM_Code  
1   1001  
2   1002  
3   1003  
4   1002  
5   1003  
6   1004  
7   1005  
8   1006  
9   1007  
10  1006
```

Now I want to get `ITEM_CODE` which exists only once. From the database I can get data by using group by shown below

```
SELECT ITEM_Code 
FROM ITEM_TABLE 
GROUP BY ITEM_Code  
HAVING COUNT(ITEM_Code) = 1
```

Result:

```
ITEM_CODE  
1001  
1004  
1005  
1007
```

I have `ITEM_TABLE` data in ADO.NET datatable

I want to get `ITEM_CODE` which exists only once from the ADO.NET `Datatable` into any variable.

How can I do this in an optimum way?